# After a bufferoverflow does an attacker only have access to calls which are present in the library where the C code was compiled?

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, c

Or are there techniques to just get a shell?

What I am interested in is if I have compiled some C code using only a small library with insignificant possible calls, does this restrict the attacker from doing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably helps a little, raising the bar and requiring a more sophisticated attack, but I wouldn't hang my security hat on this.

The better way to think about it is that, in the worst case, they have the ability to add arbitrary code to your program. They can do anything that C code can do, including read/writes to files on your filesystem (ie reading your data or inserting backdoors into other programs) or calling `exec()` to run other programs. So yes, a buffer overflow can do anything a shell can do.

If you want to be on the safe side, consider a buffer overflow to be game over and instead spend your time and effort on [defence in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) around the service that could be vulnerable. For example limiting who can send data to this service by putting it behind an authentication server, firewalls, and [deep packet inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection); follow the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) to lock down privileges of the user running the service, etc.

**TL;DR**: good developers should always be double-checking their code to avoid having buffer overflows or null pointer dereferences, meanwhile good sys admins should always assume the devs have been sloppy and wrap the service in an onion of security to minimize the potential damage.

Comment: In reality (with NX+ASLR), you can't usually execute arbitrary code from a buffer overflow. You're limited to (ab)using the compiled code, so a smaller binary with less library calls will be harder to exploit.

Comment: @grc if you put up a better answer's I'll happily upvote it.

Comment: @whatever489 Sorry for the generic answer, I know it's not really what you were looking for. If somebody does post an answer analyzing what can be exploited through a buffer overflow, I'd love to read it too!

Comment: @MikeOunsworth your answer is great, in short this would only prevent script kiddies from accessing the system over time? But wouldn't it give the sys admins time to see that something is acting fishy if the attackers would have to think about loading new libraries in the injection?

Comment: @whatever489 Maybe it would tip off the sys admins, or maybe advanced hackers (like those employed by government cyber warfare departments) can get in, plant their persistent backdoor, extract their data, and clean up any traces of the attack all in a minute or two. Trouble is: we have no idea what the best hackers are capable of, so I always assume the worst.

Comment: If the binary is dynamically linked, it'll almost surely also be linked to libc, which is quite large. So even with NX+ASLR etc., a ROP chain could be built and arbitrary code executed.

Comment: @domen with ASLR on, you'd need some kind of leak to know where libc is.

Comment: I know. I'm just saying that attacker is not limited to that small library, but to whole libc which is implicitly linked.